# How to keep custom kernel modules on kernel updates installed?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, linux-kernel, kernel-modules

I've got a NIC (Asus XG C100C) that is not properly supported in the current Linux kernel. Hence, I installed driver which I compiled from source. Every time when the kernel is updated, I have to reinstall it and copy the `atlantic.ko` to `/lib/modules/<KERNELVERSION>/` and use `insmod` to install it.

I assume the driver is compatible with most minor kernel updates/patches. Is there any way to copy/install the driver (atlantic.ko) somewhere else, so that the kernel update procedure is installing it for new kernel versions automatically?

- OS: Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS (Xenial Xerus)
- Kernel: 4.4.0-140-generic
- NIC-Driver: "atlantic.ko" (from ASUS-Website, Release Date 26-01-2017)
- NIC: Asus XG C100C

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A lot of external/third party kernel modules utilise [DKMS](https://github.com/dell/dkms) for this sort of thing.

Comment: Thx! This hopefully did it! -- For others: https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/DKMS/ has a quick tutorial on how to install drivers into the DKMS framework. It's just some copying of the source code to a special directory and writing a short dkms.cfg. It successfully built/installed the driver after I removed my manual installation. DKMS itself was already installed and configured for my nvidia driver for which it worked fine so far (I just did not know). Now, I'm waiting for the next kernel update to see it's real magic happening! :)